# Add google maps event listener to custom close button in InfoWindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

currently I'm trying to implement my own custom Info Windows in Google Maps. I've found quite a good tutorial about [5 ways to customize Google's InfoWindow](http://en.marnoto.com/2014/09/5-formas-de-personalizar-infowindow.html). From the tutorial I've successfully creates my own custom Info Windows, however I couldn't be able to implement my own close button in the Info Windows.

From the codes, I created my own close button that attached to InfoWindows' content.

`<span id="iw-close-btn"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-times white"></i></span>`

And then I add event listener to the element using **maps.google.event.addDomListener()** :

```
var closeBtn = $('#iw-close-btn').get();
google.maps.event.addListener(closeBtn, 'click', function() {
   console.log('closed');
   infowindow.close();
});
```

But it doesn't work whenever I tried to click the element (the log also doesn't appear).

Here's my whole sample code using codepen.io :
http://codepen.io/dannypranoto/pen/PNdvzb

Could you please help me with a solution? Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You say you add the event listener using `addDomListener` but your code shows the use of `addListener` instead.
2. The way you identify your close button is not correct. A simple look at your javascript console should tell you that. Use `closeBtn[0]` instead.

So the complete code would be:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {

    var closeBtn = $('#iw-close-btn').get();

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeBtn[0], 'click', function() {

        infowindow.close();
    });
});
```

<kbd>[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqvjyR)</kbd>